# Bash doesn't create all files and directories with loop

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a directory with list of directories with list of files.
Could you explain me, why this script doesn't work properly?

```sh
createapp() {
    local folders=('graphql' 'migrations' 'models' 'tests')
    local files=('__init__.py' 'admin.py' 'apps.py' 'views.py')

    cd backend/apps
    mkdir $COMMAND2
    cd $COMMAND2

    for folder in $folders
        do mkdir $folder && cd $folder
        for file in $files
            do touch $file && cd ..
        done
    done
}
```

It creates a `graphql` directory, and an `__init__.py` file in it, but that's all.

Comment: `for folder in $folders` does not iterate over the array.

Comment: You want `for directory in "${folders[@]}"`

Comment: You don't really need the `cd` command. After `mkdir "$folder"`, just do `touch "$folder/$file"`. Right now, you are executing `cd ..` too soon: you want to do that *after* the file loop completes.

Comment: @chepner thank you

Comment: @WilliamPursell and you also <3

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems:

1. You aren't iterating over the contents of the array, only the first element.
2. You are executing `cd ..` too soon; you want to do that *after* the loop that creates each file.

---

```
for folder in "${folders[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "$folder" &&
  cd "$folder" &&
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    touch "$file"
  done && 
  cd ..
done
```

There are two ways to simplify this. If you keep the `cd` command, you only need one call to `touch`:

```
for folder in "${folders[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "$folder" && cd "$folder" && touch "${files[@]}" && cd ..
done
```

Or you can get rid of the `cd` command, and pass a longer path to `touch`:

```
for folder in "${folders[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "$folder" &&
  for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    touch "$folder/$file"
  done
done
```

or even

```
for folder in "${folders[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "$folder" &&
  touch "${files[@]/#/$folder/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get fancy, you can do all of this with ***zero*** loops and a combination of [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) brace and array expansions:

```
#!/bin/bash

createapp() {
    local folders=('graphql' 'migrations' 'models' 'tests')
    local files=('__init__.py' 'admin.py' 'apps.py' 'views.py')

    IFS=,
    eval mkdir -p "{${folders[*]}}"
    eval touch "{${folders[*]}}/{${files[*]}}"
}
```

Note that the use of `eval` can be dangerous, but it's pretty limited in this implementation as the two arrays are local and not using user-defined input.  If this was [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), you could embed brace and array expansion without the need for `eval`